# getting error as too many values in my query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
dpt_no   salary  period        start_date       end_date
------   -----   ------        ----------       --------
100 12580   15months    12-DEC-07   10-DEC-10
101 15500   19months    10-JAN-07   10-DEC-11
102 7777    18months    11-JUL-07   21-APR-11
103 9999    11months    07-JUL-07   31-JAN-11
104 8500    9months         12-MAR-07   27-MAR-11
105 10000   20months    17-SEP-07   01-AUG-11
106 25000   7months         17-NOV-07   26-JUL-11
107 100000  6months     05-MAY-07   21-JUN-11
108 35000   16months    28-FEB-08   21-JUN-11
109 5000    16months    02-DEC-08   19-AUG-11
```

i'm write query for giving rank to salary and getting that rank using ampersand. That query is

```
select salary from salary 
where &RANK=(select salary, rank() over(order by salary desc) 
as "rank" from salary  salary).
```

BUT i'm getting error as "too many values". can any one help me please

Comment: You can use this to get rank and append ampersand to it.SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS RANK from salary.

Comment: then where ampersand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
select t1.salary from 
(select salary.salary, 
         rank() over(order by salary desc) 
as "rank" from salary) t1
where "rank"=&RANK
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d892a/5)

Comment: your  query showing error as"SQl command is not properly ended"

Comment: right answer.for example in salary column have multiple duplicates values.the rank function give same rank.how to rectify that

Comment: @ram: In this case use ROW_NUMBER() instead if RANK()

Comment: @ram [Dense_rank()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183572/whats-the-difference-between-rank-and-dense-rank-functions-in-oracle)