# How to give Rank in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, rank

```
select * from (select sum(dpt_no) as numbers from department group by dpt_name) order by numbers desc
```

**Result:**

```
  NUMBERS
----------
       420 
       209 
       106 
       105 
       103 
       102
```

How to give ranks to this result?

Comment: Are you looking for sth like that [link](http://psoug.org/definition/RANK.htm)

Comment: already i saw that,but how to give rank for my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
    numbers,
    rank() over(order by numbers desc) Rank
from (
    select sum(dpt_no) as numbers 
    from department group by dpt_name
) 
order by numbers desc
```

sample:

```
select 
  Col,
  rank() over(order by Col desc) Rank
From YourTable
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d63ec/3)

Comment: can you tell one thing.What is  the major difference between RANK and DENSE_RANK?

Comment: Plz check the links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183572/whats-the-difference-between-rank-and-dense-rank-functions-in-oracle http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions.php

Comment: RANK allows gaps if any rows tie in value - e.g. 1,2,2,4,5; DENSE_RANK does not include any gaps - e.g. 1,2,2,3,4; ROW_NUMBER, on the other hand, resolves ties nondeterministically, e.g. 1,2,3,4,5