# Assigned unique ID to a group of same values

Tags: sql

Ok so I have a group of information like this:

```
2014-01 2014-1-1
2014-01 2014-1-2
2014-01 2014-1-3
2014-02 2014-2-1
2014-02 2014-2-2
```

I want to create another column so it will look like this:
(order)

```
1     2014-01 2014-1-1
1     2014-01 2014-1-2
1     2014-01 2014-1-3
2     2014-02 2014-2-1
2     2014-02 2014-2-2
```

I tried the rank function but it didnt' help, only give me 1,2,3,4,5 value throughout

```
1     2014-01 2014-1-1
2     2014-01 2014-1-2
3     2014-01 2014-1-3
4     2014-02 2014-2-1
5     2014-02 2014-2-2
```

Anyone please help...?thanks

Comment: Regarding your title, an identifier that repeats is not unique.

Answer (score 3):

You should show the query that you tried.  In any case, you want `dense_rank()`:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by col1) , col1, col2
from table t;
```

If those two values are actually in *one* column, then do:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by left(col, 7)), col
from table t;
```

Comment: FYI, [here is a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11183572/642706) that compares `rank` and `dense_rank`.