# Saving DENSE_RANK() in a dedicated column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have an application that needs precise order of items in a table based on datetime item (actually, autoincrement Id primary key) was created. It has to be without gaps and once created, never changed. Order number is later used as a legal identifier (its just a requirement).
There could be thousands of items per partition.

Question is what is the better practice:

1) Calculate DENSE_RANK() on each retrieval of item from DB (which means calculating it over thousands of items)

OR

2) Calculate it on item creation and save in a dedicated column?

Additionally, if 2) is the better option, is there a way to optimize calculating it so that it starts from the previous one that has order number assigned or is it safer to always run DENSE_RANK() function on full partition?

Comment: you might like to read this as well meanwhile we post solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183572/whats-the-difference-between-rank-and-dense-rank-functions-in-oracle

Comment: i am aware of differences between rank, dense_rank and row_number but its a very good read, thank you!

Comment: If Order number is a legal requirement maybe you should dedicate a column to it and populate it during the creation.