# Custom ROW_NUMBER Function

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

Is there a way to write a row_number() function such that the column below titled (HELP HERE) can be achieved? I want to be able to rank columns a through d into buckets per the data in column d.

`a      b   c       d  (HELP HERE)
 1603   82  117276  36  1
 1603   82  117276  36  1
 1603   82  117276  37  2
 1603   82  117276  37  2`

If I try `row_number() over (partition by a,b,c order by d)` the data reacts like this

`a      b   c       d  (HELP HERE)
 1603   82  117276  36  1
 1603   82  117276  36  2
 1603   82  117276  37  1
 1603   82  117276  37  2`

Comment: `rank()` or `dense_rank()` window function ought to do it. Here's an SO question explaining the difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183572/whats-the-difference-between-rank-and-dense-rank-functions-in-oracle

Comment: ?? If you try row_number() like you show, the HELP HERE column will have values 1, 2, 3, 4 - not 1, 2, 1, 2 as you show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try dense_rank() over (order by d)